# gnupg with php throws "could not init keylist"

Tags: php, linux, gnupg

Trying to encrypt mails with gnupg, the method call `gnupg::keyinfo()` throws the error `could not init keylist`.

This is how I initialize the extension:

```
putenv('GPGME_DEBUG=9:./gnupg/debug.log');
putenv('GNUPGHOME=./gnupg/');

$this->gpg = new gnupg();
$this->gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION);
```

Where gnupg really does exist (calling `is_dir('./gnupg')` returns `true` - I've also tried the absolute path without success).

Some additional information:

- the exactly same code DOES work using `PHP-CLI`. (However, I need it using HTTP)
- I'm using an ubuntu webserver: `Linux name 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- gnupg version: `gpg --version` -> `gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.10`
- infrastructure: `client`  -> `nginx` -> `apache` -> `php 5.3`
- for testing, I've set the file permissions (recursively): `drwxrwxrwx  4 www-data web1     4096 29. Nov 12:30 .`

The debug.log shows the following error:

```
_gpgme_io_set_close_notify (fd=0x282): enter: close_handler=0x7f6d2a409780/0x7f6d38edb730
_gpgme_io_set_close_notify (fd=0x282): error: Invalid argument
```

The full debug log is uploded here: http://nopaste.penguinfriends.org/view/84317/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Could you dump the "php -i" output?

Answer (score 2):

When you run from the command line, the `GNUPGHOME` path you specified is relative to your working directory where you are when you run the script. From a web environment you can't rely on a particular working directory so you may need to specify the full absolute path to your gnupg directory. You could, however, specify the path relative to the current script:

```
putenv('GNUPGHOME='.dirname(__FILE__).'/gnupg');
```

Also, you shouldn't ever use `777` permissions, especially with programs related to security like `ssh` and `gnupg` that may check and refuse, but `775` might have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the php5 version of gnupg supports only version 1 of gnupg.  However, the debian/ubuntu version of libgpgme11-dev was compiled using gpg version 2.

I wasn't able to find a clean solution using gpg.conf to specify which version of the gpg engine to use.  So, I ended up removing (apt-get remove) gpg2 (and libgpgme11-dev) from my system and compiling GPGME from source.  Then I reinstalled the php5 gnupg extension and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am late to the party, but I would like to share how I solved this issue. First, I tried to execute the script as Apache user (executing it from the command line as my own user works flawlessly, as stated by the OP):

`# su -s /bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/gnupg.php' www-data`

And this is where I obtained the same error. So I tried some things:

- *Temporally* added a /bin/bash to www-data in `/etc/passwd` to execute some commands with a proper shell (replace `/usr/sbin/nologin` by `/bin/bash`)
- Open an interactive shell as www-data: `sudo -u www-data -i`
- Generate a keyring with `gpg --gen-key` (it will create this folder /var/www/.gnupg with proper permissions
- Import your {public,secret} keys
- Remember to restore the `/usr/sbin/nologin` no-shell to www-data user in `/etc/passwd`

Now this script works as expected also as www-data :)

```
<?php

// make sure that this folder is NOT accesible as an URL
putenv("GNUPGHOME=/var/www/.gnupg/");

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$res = gnupg_init();
gnupg_seterrormode($res,GNUPG_ERROR_WARNING);

$info = gnupg_keyinfo($res, '');
echo "Key - Info<pre>";
var_dump($info);
echo "</pre>";
```